# Login Button CSS

Tags: login, css, buttons

I'm trying to find the Login button CSS code.

I tryed this topic, but i think the path has changed after wordpress updated:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-login-button-color

Any can show me where is it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS comes from `wp-includes/css/buttons.css`. Do not change this this file; it will be overridden during the  next update. Create a separate plugin instead, or add some custom code to your theme’s `functions.php`, and hook into `login_head`:

```
add_action( 'login_head', function() {
    ?>
<style>
.button {
    background: red !important;
}
</style>
    <?php
});
```

[image]